# The best way to retrieve data of a range of different child components in React Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am quite new to react js. Have searched a bit but haven't got an answer to this question:

Suppose I have two dynamic input tables in my page, and each of them is a separate component. And the lines are different components (React classes) as well. And on the page, there is a save button. Once the save button is clicked, all the information of the page should be gathered and pushed to server as a JSON string.

The very obvious approach for me is to gather the information via jQuery. This will definitely work. But it makes me feel it is not the react way of doing it. Since react data is one way binding, I am not quite sure how to handle this situation more appropriately. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should post your code as well. My suggestion is to use React state for this

Comment: @Ved Actually, I don't have the code. I wrote my previous page using pure handlebar js and I am still thinking about how to structure the page. Are you suggesting that I put the whole object as a state and update the state on every change event? That will do. But I am not sure whether it is the correct way though

Comment: Yes, you should to do this via state. Whenever you update your state, it will only update the changes on object rather than updating whole object.

Comment: @Ved I understand. This will definitely be a valid way. The drawback is not too bad. Actually since there is no rerendering, it doesn't even update the changes. And the extra events won't be too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, there are a few ways of doing this.

**1. Using [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html).**

You can assign references to input fields and then loop through them to get the values. The good thing about this approach is that no events are needed, but you still have to somehow know the reference to each. It adds complexity if you have dynamic fields or heavily nested fields. This is still my preferred way, mainly because you don't need events (e.g. keyup, blur, change, depending on your usage)

**2. Using state**

This makes it easier to instantly get values, if the values are updated in state as soon as the user makes a change to the field. Obviously you will need to know when a change has been made so you need events.

Your event callback can do one of many things, such as

- update a global state object (e.g. via redux)
- update form's values (or state) object via [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) usage

I hope this helps plan your forms.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the refs way is basically the jQuery way. There isn't much difference between looping through refs and classes. I agree both ways would work. But either has its own disadvantages though. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Refs are and are not the jQuery way. You can use them to access value such as `this.myField.value` or the access a components method for retrieving complex value such as from combo boxes that have separate display and value properties e.g `this.myComboComponent.getValue()`. Agreed on disadvantages. I'm glad you can see that :)

Answer (score 1):

Please check out this simplified example: https://jsfiddle.net/352v4n72/2/

It has three components. The most basic one is `Input`, which informs its parent when the value is changed:

```
var Input = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <input type="text" placeholder={this.props.name}
            onChange={e => this.props.onInputChange(e.currentTarget.value)} />
    );
  }
});
```

Now, its parent component, `Line`:

```
var Line = React.createClass({
  onInputChange(inputId, value) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[inputId] = value;
    this.setState(obj, state => {
      this.props.onLineChange(this.props.lineId, this.state);
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
        <Input name="firstName" onInputChange={value => this.onInputChange('firstName', value)} />
        <Input name="lastName" onInputChange={value => this.onInputChange('lastName', value)} />
        <Input name="email" onInputChange={value => this.onInputChange('email', value)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

This component holds three `Input` components. When each of them changes, the `onInputChange` function is called, and this function basically aggregates all the input values, creating a whole "line" data.

The last component is `Table`:

```
var Table = React.createClass({
  onLineChange(lineId, value) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[lineId] = value;
    this.setState(obj, state => console.log(this.state));

  },
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
        <Line lineId={1} onLineChange={this.onLineChange} />
        <Line lineId={2} onLineChange={this.onLineChange} />
        <Line lineId={3} onLineChange={this.onLineChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

This component holds three lines, and just like the line aggregates `Input`'s, `Table` aggregates `Line`'s. You can see the state as it changes in the console.